# Pigment returning to my grey

Tags: hair

In the past I dyed my hair to cover the grey, but it became a more frequent event so I decided to just go grey.  My hair has been almost entirely white for nearly 20 years.  The pigment has been returning to my hair gradually for the last 18 months.  Do you have any explanation for this?  I have tried to research this, but have not found any answers.  There is information for reasons why hair looses pigmentation, but not for its return.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! Personal health questions aren't allowed here, but your question might be adaptable into a more general question about pigmentation that could be answered. Check out the [Help](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I can't explain the phenomenon, but have experienced it to a lesser extent as well. And I studied dermatology. I thought it was impossible. Clearly it's not.

Comment: Do you get any new medications in that time?

Comment: There have been more questions on exactly this phenomenon on this site. Unfortunately it's off topic as said by others.